# Cannot display Google Map in a dynamically generated div

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, pagemethods

I am attempting to display a Google Map in a div which is created through a PageMethod call to a C# program.  The Pagemethod returns generated html code which is inserted into my webpage with a jquery command  $('.showitems').html(somecode);  This code contains a div in which I want to place a Google map but when I execute my javascript to create a Google map it replaces the div with spaces and no map.  However, if I hard code a div for containing the map, the javascript for creating a Google map works.  So my question is, why can't I create a Google map with dynamically generated html code?  Below is my code for creating a Google map which has been working for years except for a dynamically generated div.

```
function ShowDinerItems(dinerkey) {

            document.getElementById('HiddenDinerID').value = dinerkey;
            var latitude = document.getElementById("Hiddenlat").value;
            var longitude = document.getElementById("Hiddenlng").value;
            location = document.getElementById("LocationText").textContent;

            PageMethods.CallShowDinerItems(dinerkey, latitude, longitude, location, OnShowDinerComplete, OnShowDinerError, dinerkey);
        }

    function OnShowDinerComplete(result, dinerkey) {


              $('.showitems').html(result[0]);
              }
```

The showitems area listed above has a span area for clicking to get the map as shown below:

```
<span style="cursor:pointer" onclick=\"DisplayDinerMap('40.0912345', '89.12345', `'m0001', 'diner name')\">  Map </span>`

<div id="m0001" style="height:200px; width:200px;display:inline">map</div>
```

The dynamically generated div map looks like this in the showitems div where "m001" is the id for map1".

```
function markDiner(lat, lng, content, map1) {

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(map1), {
                zoom: 14,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
                map: map,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                title: content
            });

        }
```

I call the Map function after a user clicks on the map link. In debug mode I can see that execution goes thru the Map routine.

```
 function DisplayDinerMap(lat, lng, map1, dinername) {

            markDiner(lat, lng, dinername, map1);
}
```

If map1 is hard coded, the Google map works.  If it is generated dynamically from a call to a PageMethod it does not display a map but instead displays spaces over a literal I have coded just to see if it goes away.  So in the above example, the text "map" goes away when I try to display the map.  Any advice or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Where do you calling markDiner(lat, lng, content, map1) ?, post some more code would be more specific to clear it.

Comment: I have updated my entry to show more code.  Hope this makes it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a delegation to the span you are using to trigger the event.